# KnpPaginatorBundleで、page以外の引数を追加する方法

Tags: symfony2

symfony2で、ページングにKnpPaginatorBundleを使いたいのですが、
検索結果などの一覧で、検索条件をページングに含めたい場合の記述方法が分かりません。

/blog/2016/02

というURLでアクセスしたアクションで
2016はyear、02はmonthという名前で取得できている場合に、
2ページ目にyear=2016&month=02というクエリを追加したいのですが、
記述方法を教えてください。

$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$posts = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, 3);

ここにどうにかして追加するのではと思うのですが
書き方が見つかりませんでした。。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決したので記述します。
どうやらknp_paginator自体にパラメーターを渡す機能はなさそうでした。
アクションで以下のように実装し、

```
$param = array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month);
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, 3);
return $this->render('Notice/index.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination, 'param' => $param));
```

テンプレには

```
{% if pagination.totalItemCount > 0 %}
{% include "Common/pager.twig" with { 'pages' : pagination.paginationData, 'param': param, 'route' => 'notice_index' } %}
{% endif %}
```

pager.twigの中身は

```
{% if pages.previous is defined %}
<li><a href="{{ path(routes, param|merge({'page': pages.previous})) }}" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">前へ</span></a></li>
{% endif %}

{% for page in pages.pagesInRange %}
<li{% if page == pages.current %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(routes, param|merge({'page': page})) }}"><span>{{ page }}</span></a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% if pages.next is defined %}
<li><a href="{{ path(routes, param|merge({'page': pages.next})) }}" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">次へ</span></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

こんな感じで実装して動きました。